# Totally form Disposing and free up memory

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resources, dispose

I already read a ton of topics "class disposing" about and I did understand how to do it and it works fine! Meanwhile "form  disposind" is not same and resources still leaking!

What I am doing:

Initializing form by "using" method:

```
Using f as New Form
    f.ShowDialog()
    'my code
End using
```

In this case by "end using" form terminated with "Dispose" method.

For example:

I have a form which have a class (it contain parameters and other classes).
On initialization form event, form (itself) take 12Mb of memory (I measure it in process explorer) and plus my class take 10Mb (which Disposable and also disposing before Dispose form on Dispose event). After my form disposed (I measure it again) I see my class disposed and resources (of class) are free totaly, the form is not freeing resources. In other words I kill 10Mb (of class) BUT DON'T kill 12Mb (of form).

My Dispose code:

```
Private Sub Form_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Me.Disposed
    If Not fDisposed Then
        MyPersonalClass.Dispose()'class
        MyPersonalClass = Nothing
        fDisposed = True
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        GC.Collect()
        Finalize()
    End If
End Sub
```

It's very bad. If most of time I working with these forms and if they are don't free resources after dispose, each opened form will be leave approx 10-12Mb in memory after closed. And if I open my form 100 times it will freezes more then 1Gb of memory.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: You should dispose of the resource you initialize inside those Forms. Or wait until the GC collects them. It may take its sweet time, but it knows what it's doing. Anyway, if you create a **disposable** object, then dispose of it when you're done with it. It will help. Take special care of graphics objects, they're more *delicate* (in a way). Try to instantiate and dispose of them in place. Give or take the same with data-related classes. You're too much concerned with Forms.

Comment: I don't understand. Must I kill everithing  of controls in Form? I thought all controls removing by "Sub Finalize" (as conponent destructor) of form. And how I must wait until GC collect? Must I put GC Collect after "end using"? Or what?

Comment: An `Using` block is just a helper. It disposes of a disposable object implicitly (in the Finally part of Try block). Don't consider the Controls inside a Form. A Form has already a `Dispose()` method that will be called when you `Close()` it. Take care of the disposable objects **you** create (Bitmaps , for examples). When  IntelliSense tells you that an object has a Dispose() method, then use it when you're done with that object. Or declare it in a Using block, if possible. Sometimes it's better to `Dispose()` of it. Sometimes `Using` it. It depends on the context and the object.

Comment: My form have a lot of controls (as comboboxes, labels, tablelayoutpanel, textboxes etc). Must I put each of them in dispose function (for example Combobox.Dispose) or how can I dispose it?

Comment: Let alone Forms and Controls. Do mind what you put inside of them and where it comes from. Btw, *a lot of controls* doesn't mean much, nobody knows what's *a lot*.

Comment: Can you say it simply? Write example please! Now I tried dispose some of Form controls and memory still leaked!

Comment: @AndrewMorton My Comboboxes have datasource to datatable. I tried set datasource = nothing and clear comboboxes by .Items.Clear() and .Clear(), memory still leaking. Can anyone write a real function or method with example to dispose? All people write a methods, but I already know it and tried all of them. I tried it for 2 weeks and nothing results!

Comment: @AndrewMorton OMG I alreade read (here, msdn and many other sites) all of you wrote. Do you can WRITE HOW TO free up memory or not? Why you are writing same again and again? I said I already read all of you write here and I DON'T UNDERSTAND how to free memory resources.
I need method or function or property or link to site or somthing else but I don't need words empty of meaning! Please read my topic again. My classes free memory resources by disposing, but form itself don't free memory by disposing!

Comment: @AndrewMorton 12Mb*100 times = 1Gb. And doesn't matters modern computer or not modern. It's too much! And as I see _The .NET framework_ **DON'T** _takes care of memory management for_ me otherwise I don't wrote this post!

Comment: @Andy I suspect you are not really leaking memory, but have objects that are marked for deletion that have not yet been deleted. Garbage Collection works that way, it saves time by not always completing the recovery of memory unless that memory is needed. As others have said, .Net will manage the "managed objects" and you should let it do its job.

Comment: If you have PictureBoxes and you assign different Bitmaps without disposing of the old object before assogning a new one, the memory your application uses can grow quickly. That's an example. Nobody can write you a *Global Dispose* method. You have to take care of your disposable objects when/where you use them. What is a disposable object is quite simple: an object that provides a `Dispose()` method. The MSDN Docs on .Net objects also have a quite visible note that informs you about this detail. If you are unsure whether you should dispose of an object you just created, see the Docs about it.

Comment: I need to know if this issue was ever resolved. I am having a similar situation. The memory is never garbage collected. VS2019 shows up to 4GB of memory just sitting there uncollected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `VB`, but I think it will do things similar as to how they are done using winforms for C#

The easiest way to make sure that all Disposable objects of A `Form` are disposed when the form is disposed, to keep a collection of Disposable objects. You could use the existing class [Sytem.ComponentModel.Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.container?view=netframework-4.7.2) class for this. The disadvantage is that it only accepts objects that implement [interface IComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icomponent?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you have only a few classes that must be disposed that don't have this interface yet, this is the easiest method. Otherwise design your own `DisposableCollection`

```
class DisposableCollection : List<object>, IDisposable
{
     public bool IsDisposed {get, private set} = false;

     private IEnumerable<IDisposable> DisposableItems => this.OfType<IDisposable>();

     public void Dispose()
     {
         if (!this.IsDisposed)
         {
               // Dispose all disposable items
               foreach (IDisposable disposableItem in this.DisposableItems)
               {
                   disposableItem.Dispose();
               }
               this.disposed = true;
         }  
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
     private readonly DisposableCollection disposables = new DisposableCollection();

     public MyForm()
     {
          // create and add all your items to disposables
     }

     protected override void OnDisposing(bool disposing)
     {
           this.disposables.Dispose();
     }
}
```

If desired you can add event handlers to notify others that the object is being disposed

Comment: What kind of items must I add to Disposable collection: comboboxex, tablelayoutpanel, textboxes etc or all of them?

Comment: It is good practice to Dispose all objects that implement IDisposable as soon as they are not needed anymore